# FiddlerScript: proxy QUERY STRING and POST data in autoresponder

Tags: proxy, fiddler

On the Autoresponder I map a certain endpoint to respond to a certain URL request received.
I would like the endpoint receives the QUERY STRING and POST DATA, too.

I thought it was possible through the "REGEX:" wrapper in the rule, but it cannot capture any subexpression to pass to the mapped endpoint.

Can it be done through FiddlerScript? How to reference request and mapped endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

This solution in C# allows to incercept the request to [www.example-1.com](http://www.example-1.com) and forward it to [www.example-2.com](http://www.example-2.com), chaining possible query string and filling POSTDATA if given:

```
// match regex
string regex = "example-1.com/somepath/.*";
Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);
Match match = rgx.Match(oSession.fullUrl);

if (match.Success) {
    // GET request -> replace the original URL with "https://www.example-2.com"
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("GET")) {
        string qs = oSession.fullUrl.Split('?')[1];
        oSession.fullUrl = oSession.fullUrl.Replace(oSession.fullUrl, "https://www.example-2.com/path?" + qs);
    } else if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST")) {
        // Create an HTTP request to www.example-2.com and forward the request body saved above:
        oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
        
        var reqBody = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqBody);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://plugvue.com/test/request-parser/api-write.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

It has to be put inside the OnBeforeRequest(Session oSession) handler.